# Сохранять базу данных каждую неделю

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, события

Возможно ли используя events в phpMyAdmin создать event который позволит мне каждую неделю сохранять базу данных в папку?

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы сохранять БД каждую неделю (каждый понедельник в 00:00), можно с помощью `cron'a` выполнять команду `mysqldump`

В правило `cron`

```
00 00 * * 1 mysqldump -u{пользователь} -p{пароль} --all-databases > /{path_to_backups}/mysqldump_`$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S)`.sql
```

Comment: ищу способ сделать это именно с помощью event. Можно ли как то это сделать с помощью event в phpMyAdmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin - это web интерфейс. Используйте mysqldump